# Windows domain GPO applied to users but excluded in some computers

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016

Is there any way to apply a user GPO (example network shared folder letter mapping) to be excluded when the user login into some specific computers group?

I know I can define the scope of GPO filtering by user or computer groups, but I cannot mix the filter because the GPO has some computer rules and user rules. What I'm looking for is how to limit an user rule GPO when the user is logging from some computer.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking `I want the user GPO to apply when the user logs onto ComputerX` or are you asking `I do NOT want the user GPO to apply when the user logs onto ComputerX`?

Comment: IIRC, GPO security filtering based on the computer *does* affect user rules nowadays.  It didn't used to, but that got changed a few years back.  Not sure whether that solves your problem, and even less sure that it is a *sensible* solution to your problem - loopback mode is usually preferable, IMO - but it may be worth knowing.

Comment: @joeqwerty I want to apply an user rule to all computers excluding a particular computer group. The main point is I'm not sure if you can control user rules based on computer group/uo instead of user group/uo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the computer must be able to **Read** the GPO before the user can **Apply** it.

So, in the **Delegation** tab, add the group of computers to be excluded and check "Deny" for "Read".

These computers won't be able to read the policy, so the users on these computers won't be able to apply this policy.